# Will current WP7.x & WP8.x apps continue to work with Windows 10 for phones?

Tags: apps, windows-10-mobile, compatibility

With Microsoft pushing Universal Apps for everything Windows 10 (PCs, tablets, phones, Xbox) I wonder if non-universal apps currently available in the store will continue to work on Windows 10 (at least on phones). I assume this will work, but I haven't read any official statement yet.

Comment: I've wondered about this too. Because if there's just one Store, then all current WP apps would have to run on Windows RT. And if they don't, will all those apps become worthless?

Comment: at least from a technical point of view it should work as both Windows RT and Windows Phone are on-chip systems.

Comment: You mean the apps now on the WP store would run on the PC's?

Comment: yes, technically it should be possible - on PC in general but on RT devices in particular.

Comment: I wonder why they wouldn't have done that with Windows 8, then. Especially with how much they were pushing the "universal" part of things.

Comment: @Drowin there's already only one store, but developers can choose to target phone, PC or both 8.1 variants.

Comment: @RowlandShaw What do you mean "there's one store"? When you go to publish an app, you have the option of publishing it to the Windows Phone Store, or the Windows Store. True, you can develop the same app for both platforms fairly easily with universal apps, but I think there are two separate stores...?

Comment: @Drowin I'm sure there was a blog post last year about how they've merged the stores, although the closest I can find right now is [this post from Todd Brix](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/06/unifying-developer-registration-windows-and-windows-phone-2/). I'd suggest that the premise of universal apps effectively *requires* a single common store, even if developers have to explicitly publish separately to phone and to desktop, albeit with the same developer account.

Comment: I don't think they have one single store yet. As a developer I still need to upload a Windows Store app and a Windows Phone app in two different locations if I want to target both platforms - even with universal apps.

Comment: @RowlandShaw Maybe I'm wrong, but what I take from that article is that they have merged the Store *teams* (on MS's end) and *registrations*; not the stores themselves.

Comment: yeah, you do only need one account (and pay only once) to get access to both stores.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After installing Windows 10 Technical Preview I can confirm that WP7.x and WP8.x app work fine on Windows 10 for phones.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are there two stores, or did they port the current WP apps to a new store?

Comment: the store seems to be exactely the same as in 8.1 atm.

Answer (score 4):

There was already a statement that [Windows Phone 8 devices will be upgradable to Windows 10](https://twitter.com/Lumia/status/532128314467823616).

I'd be surprised if they were to release an upgrade that would stop previous purchases from working following upgrade of the operating system. I'd also be surprised if there weren't still phone specific apps (like [Here Drive+](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=31bbc68c-503e-4561-8d85-a294d54df06f)) whilst others may migrate to being universal apps (Like Twitter already has).

From a development point of view, universal app developers are already encouraged to target the different screen sizes/formats, and the development templates default to having different layouts for each platform (although it is possible to share them if you really want)

Comment: I do share your view that most likely all apps will continue to work - I just wonder why there's still no official statement. Also there are still a lot of non-universal apps comming into the store mostly as it's often easier to create a WP8.1 Silverlight app than a universal app.

Comment: Drive+ no longer available on WinPhone 10 :( They've taken the 'up' out of 'upgrade'...

Comment: @Benjol I can't see any missing functionality from Drive+ in Windows Maps though (granted some are more challenging to find).

Comment: @RowlandShaw, yeah, I've read varying reports going in both directions. I guess I need to try it for a bit longer.